# How many ways are there to paint a $4$-storey house with $6$ colors?

Tags: combinatorics

A $4$-storey house is to be painted by some $6$ different colors such that each storey is painted in one color. How many ways are there to paint the house?
Repetition of color is allowed.

The answer turns out to be $6^4$.  Although this seems correct to me if looking at the problem color by color I was wondering why can't the answer be $4^6$ instead looking at the problem floor by floor?

Comment: With one storey and six colours,  would the answer be $6^1$ or $1^6$?

Comment: OKAY. I understand it now. THANKS for the quick 2 min response.

Comment: What Lord Shark the Unknown did here was test the extreme case.  If the house only had one floor, we could paint it in six ways.  That tells us we are choosing colors rather than floors.  If we were choosing floors, we would get $1^6 = 1$, which does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $6^4$ means that the color repetition is allowed but the floor repetition is not allowed, while using $4^6$ means that the floor repetition is allowed (contradicts the fact that each floor can only be colored once) but the repetition of colors is not allowed.

Comment: I got it. THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are to paint one of the storey of the $4$ - storeyed house, you have $6$ possible choices. And you paint the first storey AND the second one AND the third one AND the fourth one where for each of them, you hae 6 choices. So, total choices in which you can paint your $4$ - storey house is $6^4$.

Comment: I got the answer now. THANKS to you too.